# How can I get the the local user or current user's username from Firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase

I have to get the name and subtitle of the local/current user in Firebase and display it in a string.  What's the function to do that.

I have tried the Firebase method but that was not what I needed.

My Firebase database looks something like this.

Users
  UID
    Name
    Subtitle

Comment: "I have tried the Firebase method but that was not what I needed." Please edit your question to include what you tried.

Comment: You could use - FIRAuth.auth(), to get current user and with the reference name, gender etc can be fetched, I have provided a code snippet below, Please mark as answered if it answers your query.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current user id using the below snippet

```
let userId : String = (FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!
print("Current user ID value is -- " + userId )
```

Once you have the uid, you can get its details using below

```
let thisUserRef = usersRef.childByAppendingPath(userId)
thisUserRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value... {
    let gender = snapshot.value["gender"]
    let name = snapshot.value["name"]
}
```

Comment: is it auth.auth()